# PouchDB Push Replication does not push new documents

Tags: node.js, replication, couchbase, pouchdb

Am using PouchDB version 5.2.1 with nodejs version 0.10.26. Recently I encountered a problem, where out of my two different instances of PouchDB in one instance the push replication was working fine but in other instance the push replication was not happening.
I further dug deeper into the library I found that in the file pouchdb/lib/index.js  a function named `startNextBatch()` is called. Inside the function we are checking for the condition

```
if (returnValue.cancelled || currentBatch) {
       return;
    }
```

In success scenario the currentBatch was undefined and hence the code didnt return back and the push happened, but in failure scenario the currentBatch was defined and return was called.The documents present in currentBatch variable are the previous documents which had got pushed to server but couldn't sync back due to some other issue and also the checkpoints for them couldnt be updated, hence the currentBatch variable was not cleared.

My question is :

1)What impact will it have if i comment the return from the code.

2)Why is push replication stopped because the variable currentBatch is defined.

Answer (score 0):

After some further debugging I found out that the replication has totally stopped with status code 503 unknown database error. This has happened because there is some problem with my sync gateway and some documents takes time to sync back ,hence writing checkpoints throws 503 unknown error (am not exactly sure why checkpoints are getting messed up because some documents got synced and others got synced after some time). The PouchDB library totally aborts the replication and after that no push happens.

1) If I comment the return, the current document will get pushed but since replication is aborted there will be no checkpoints saved.

2) Push replication didnt stop because currentBatch is defined. currentBatch is defined because replication is not happenning.